Настройка Docker: B24 + Laravel - ошибка Nginx
Один из сервисов в моём B24 должен быть на чистом Laravel'e.
У меня есть настройки Nginx, при котором хорошо работает B24. А также настройки на этом же сервере, при котором Laravel-сервис полностью заменяет B24 и открываются все роуты по пути https://laravel.test/ttt/test_route и тд.
Вот конфиг Nginx в этом случае:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.key;

    server_name bitrix;
    charset utf-8;
    root /var/www/services/ttt/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-bitrix:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
    }
}

И вот мой стандартный nginx конфиг для B24:
server {
    listen 80 deferred reuseport default;
    listen [::]:80 deferred reuseport default;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.key;



    server_name bitrix;
    charset utf-8;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html bitrixsetup.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-error.log;

    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
       rewrite  ^(.*)$  /bitrix/urlrewrite.php last;
    }

    rewrite ^([^.]*?\/)\/+(.*)$ $1$2 permanent;

    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
        return 301 $1;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @bitrix;
    }

    location @bitrix {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/bitrix/urlrewrite.php;
    }

    location = /restore.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        client_body_buffer_size 1024m;
        client_max_body_size 1024m;
    }

    location = /favicon.png {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ (/\.ht|/\.git|/\.gitignore|\.settings\.php|/composer|/bitrix/backup|/bitrix/updates|/bitrix/modules|/bitrix/php_interface|/bitrix/stack_cache|/bitrix/managed_cache|/bitrix/html_pages/\.|/upload/1c_exchange|local/modules|local/php_interface|/logs/) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /upload/support/not_image { internal; }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }

    location ~* ^/bitrix/cache { deny all; }

    location ~ /upload/ {
        client_body_buffer_size 1024m;
        client_max_body_size 1024m;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
            return 301 $1;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location /404.html {}
}

Я попробовал много вариантов, но результат в большинстве случаев одинаковый - на https://laravel.test/ttt/ захожу - открывается базовый роут "/", но если любой другой отличный - ошибка от Б24 (а не от Laravel).
.htaccess верный, доступы уже для теста 755 поставил на всё, www-data хозяин этой папки...
Вот что перепробовал:
1)
server {
    listen 80 deferred reuseport default;
    listen [::]:80 deferred reuseport default;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.key;

    server_name bitrix;
    charset utf-8;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html bitrixsetup.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-error.log;

    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    # Laravel часть
    location /services/ttt {
        alias /var/www/services/ttt/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /services/ttt/index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php-bitrix:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        }
    }

    # Bitrix часть
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @bitrix;
    }

    location @bitrix {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/bitrix/urlrewrite.php;
    }

    location = /restore.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        client_body_buffer_size 1024m;
        client_max_body_size 1024m;
    }

    location = /favicon.png {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ (/\.ht|/\.git|/\.gitignore|\.settings\.php|/composer|/bitrix/backup|/bitrix/updates|/bitrix/modules|/bitrix/php_interface|/bitrix/stack_cache|/bitrix/managed_cache|/bitrix/html_pages/\.|/upload/1c_exchange|local/modules|local/php_interface|/logs/) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /upload/support/not_image { internal; }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }

    location ~* ^/bitrix/cache { deny all; }

    location ~ /upload/ {
        client_body_buffer_size 1024m;
        client_max_body_size 1024m;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
            return 301 $1;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location /404.html {}
}


Вот в этом варианте /services/ttt/ обрабатывается ок, а /services/ttt/test - получаю на белом экране "File not found"

server {
    listen 80 deferred reuseport default;
    listen [::]:80 deferred reuseport default;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/sert/cert.key;

    server_name bitrix;
    charset utf-8;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html bitrixsetup.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/bitrix-error.log;

    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    # Laravel часть
    location ^~ /services/ttt/ {
        alias /var/www/services/ttt/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /services/ttt/index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php-bitrix:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            internal;
        }
    }

    # Bitrix часть
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @bitrix;
    }

    location @bitrix {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/bitrix/urlrewrite.php;
    }

    location = /restore.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        client_body_buffer_size 1024m;
        client_max_body_size 1024m;
    }

    location = /favicon.png {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ (/\.ht|/\.git|/\.gitignore|\.settings\.php|/composer|/bitrix/backup|/bitrix/updates|/bitrix/modules|/bitrix/php_interface|/bitrix/stack_cache|/bitrix/managed_cache|/bitrix/html_pages/\.|/upload/1c_exchange|local/modules|local/php_interface|/logs/) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /upload/support/not_image { internal; }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }

    location ~* ^/bitrix/cache { deny all; }

    location ~ /upload/ {
        client_body_buffer_size 1024m;
        client_max_body_size 1024m;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
            return 301 $1;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 21600;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location /404.html {}
}

В логе nginx/
192.#.#.# - - [24/Jul/2024:12:21:48 +0300] "GET /services/ttt/test HTTP/1.1" 404 47 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
На всякий случай приложу .htaccess в корне laravel'a
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

